# .NET library for generating javascript?

Tags: .net, javascript, code-generation

Do you know of a .NET library for generating javascript code?

I want to generate javascript code based on information in my .NET application. I would like to be able to create an AST-like datastructure (using C#) and have it turned into valid javascript. I need to be able to create functions, statements, expressions etc., so I need something more than a JSON serializer - but I guess you could think of this as a (*very*) generalized JSON serializer.

Do such libraries exist and if so, could you recommend any?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple I'm aware of (though have not used):

1. [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp)
2. [JSC](http://jsc.sourceforge.net/)

I hope one is of use to you.